# Incoherence when trying to use the definition of conditional probability to prove the Acceptance-Rejection method

Tags: probability, proof-writing

First of all, I believe my question will end up being pretty similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942758/acceptance-rejection-sampling-contradiction-issue) but that one was left unanswered so I believe it is fine for me to ask this again.

I just learned about the Acceptance-Rejection method and I was trying to prove it by myself. Just to set up the notation I will use, I assumed I have two families of random variables,

$$\begin{cases}\{U_i\}_{i\in\Bbb{N}} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Unif(0,1)\\
\{Y_i\}_{i\in\Bbb{N}} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} Y\end{cases}$$

where $Y$ has p.d.f. $G$. I then assume $F$ is a p.d.f. such that $F(x) \leq cG(x),\ \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$. Let $N$ be the first $N$ such that $U_N \leq \frac{F(Y_N)}{cG(Y_N)}$

Now I want to prove $F$ is the p.d.f. of $Y_N$. I wrote:

$$\begin{align}
F_{Y_N}(x) &= P\left(Y_N \leq x | U_N \leq \frac{F(Y_N)}{cG(Y_N)}\right)\\
&= P\left(Y \leq x | U \leq \frac{F(Y)}{cG(Y)}\right) \\
&= \frac{P(Y \leq x, U \leq \frac{F(Y)}{cG(Y)})}{P(U \leq \frac{F(Y)}{cG(Y)})} 
\end{align}$$

but then because $U$ and $Y$ are independent, the numerator will split in the product of the two probabilities and part of it will cancel the denominator, leaving only $P(Y \leq x) = F_Y(x)$ which is **not** what I want.

Over [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-ARM.pdf) I found a proof but they used the relation $P(A|B) = P(B|A)\times P(A)/P(B)$ to do the trick. That seems just fine to me, I just want to know what exactly is the problem with what I did, where I suspect it had to do with the way I wrote the conditional probability on the last step or with my assumption that I can split it and cancel the denominator.

Comment: Events $ Y\leq x$ and $U \leq \frac{F(Y)}{cG(Y)}$ are not independent.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 oh okay, so I can't split it; how would I go about calculating the numerator?

Comment: Use $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ as you mentioned in your question.